# Starting ActiveMQ from Tomcat application ,but using a shared datasource among instances

Tags: java, spring, apache, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a successfully running **ActiveMQ 5.9.1** , **Camel 2.11** and **Tomcat 7.0.50** service layer application with a dependency on ActiveMQ to be started independently. 
The reason Im using ActiveMQ is to have a shared datastore among 2 same load balanced instances for faster processing.

Here is what I want to do :
 To be able to start ActiveMQ from **pom.xml** or worst case scenario from **context.xml**. So, lets say 2 instances are load balanced and they start their own ActiveMQ servers but they point to a single data store(directory) for queue information. 
 Please advise how can I have such a design to sustain optimum performance in a production environment. 
 I'm still on the hunt for any psuedo code that I can try , have not succeeded yet .

Code snippet from camelContext.xml

```
<broker id="broker" brokerName="myBroker" useShutdownHook="false" useJmx="true" persistent="true" dataDirectory="activemq-data" 
        xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="tcp" uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://myBroker?create=false&amp;waitForStart=5000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <property name="maxConnections" value="8" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="activeMQConfig"
        class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="20" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="activeMQConfig" />
        <property name="transacted" value="true" />
        <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />
    </bean>
```

Please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue finally . In case somebody else is facing the same problem , I downgraded the ActivemQ version to 5.8.0 to resolve the issue.